# How to access web directory file list in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to show listview  from web directory file list. How to access web directory file list in android.

Ex:[http://mp3.com/song/](http://selangorbn.fm/song/)

this is the web directory.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
    // .getJSONfromURL("http://selangorbn.fm/song/");
    // Log.d("TAG", "json" + json);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    new Getparse().execute();
}

private void parse() throws IOException {

    String line = null, response;

    URL url = new URL("http://selangorbn.fm/song/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    while (rd.readLine() != null) {
        line += rd.readLine();
    }

    System.out.println(line);

}

public class Getparse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            parse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(integer result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}
getting null value.

Comment: You should use json or put an xml in the given URL and process that xml(which contains all the track's titles) and download the files. As far as i know you cannot all the web directory files directly.

Comment: @kumar adding json and xml end of the url its not working for me

Comment: As Audrius told you should move the processing logic away from UI Thread. Put your code in AsyncTask and move the AsyncTasck creation ton onResume() method, because onCreate should load the screen in less than 5 sec, i feel. Pls make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for you because you try to talk with Internet on the main application thread. Doing so would stall the application till the reply is received. Hence Android has internal checks. You should get [network on main thread exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) from your code.

You need to launch a separate [thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and talk with the server from there. After you get your list, use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update your results (you cannot touch any GUI elements from your  network thread).

Parsing HTML is only reasonable if this is all you can get from the uncooperative third party server. As kumar suggests, use JSON or XML if you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
                    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://test.com/appdata/0131").get();
                    doc.select("img").remove();
                    Elements links = doc.select("a");
                    List<String> listmainlinks = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<String> listweblinks = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element link : links) {
                        String linkInnerH = link.html();
                        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
                        System.out.println("linkHref: "+ linkHref);
                        System.out.println("linkInnerH: "+ linkInnerH);
                        if(linkInnerH.equals("") ||linkInnerH.equals(" ")||linkInnerH.equals(null) || linkHref.contains("?C=N;O=D")|| linkHref.contains("?C=M;O=A")||linkHref.contains("?C=S;O=A") ||linkHref.contains("?C=D;O=A")){ }
                       else if(linkHref.contains("/"))
                        {
                            if(!linkInnerH.contains("Parent Directory"))
                            listmainlinks.add(linkHref);
                        }

                        else{



                                listweblinks.add("https://test.com/appdata/0131" + linkHref);


                        }

                        }
                    System.out.println("listmainlinks "+ listmainlinks);
                    System.out.println("listweblinks "+listweblinks);
                   /* Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

                    int counter = 0;

                    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element el : img) {
                        // If alt is empty or null, add one to counter
                        if(el.attr("alt") == null || el.attr("alt").equals("")) {
                            counter++;
                        }
                        System.out.println("image tag: " + el.attr("src") + " Alt: " + el.attr("alt"));
                    }
                    System.out.println("Number of unset alt: " + counter);*/

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


https://test.com/appdata/
I/System.out: listmainlinks [0216/, 0128/, 0131/]
I/System.out: listweblinks []
https://test.com/appdata/0131/
I/System.out: listmainlinks []
I/System.out: listweblinks [https://test.com/appdata/0131/logo.png]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSOUP you can list all the files in the remote directory. But one problem i faced is if there is home page(Ex: index.html) in that directory, then it is not reading beyond that file. This is one drawback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsoup to get the href tags linking with folders with their names

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urltod).timeout(0).get();
                     doc.select("img").remove();
                     Elements links = doc.select("a");
                     List<String> listmainlinks = new ArrayList<>();
                     List<String> listnumberslinks = new ArrayList<>();
                     List<String> listweblinks = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Element link : links) {
//                       String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml();  //allhreaf incl name
                        String linkInnerH = link.html(); // foldername
                         String linkHref = link.attr("href");  //folderlink
//                      System.out.println("linkHref "+linkInnerH );
                        if(linkInnerH.equals("") ||linkInnerH.equals(" ")||linkInnerH.equals(null) ){ }
                        else{ 
                            if(linkInnerH.contains("size=\"2\"")){
                                String[] afterfonttagarray =linkInnerH.split("\">");
                                String afterfonttag = afterfonttagarray[1];
                                String[] beforefonttagarray =afterfonttag.split("</font>");
                                String beforefonttag = beforefonttagarray[0];
                                listmainlinks.add(beforefonttag);
                                listweblinks.add("http://www.abc.com/audio/"+linkHref);

                        } 
                    }

                    System.out.println("listmainlinks "+ listmainlinks); "+listnumberslinks);
                    System.out.println("listweblinks "+listweblinks);
```

this will give you the folder name as well as the links associated with them later you can use
ArrayList> albumsList to store and iterate to list or anything